# Winning chance in crooked best-of-2n+1

Tags: probability, combinatorics, game-theory

I've got this question for a uni assignment where I have to calculate my winning change in a version of best-of-2n+1. It goes like this:

- I have a 50/50 chance of winning each game
- My opponent has to win n+1 games to win the best-of-2n+1
- I have to win only n games to win the best-of-2n+1

What I have so far is:

$P($I win$) \ = \sum_{k=n}^{2n} P($I win in k games$)$

*note that I cant win in 2n+1 games*

$= \sum_{k=n}^{2n} (\frac{1}{2})^k \cdot$ [Nr of ways where I win after k games]

$= \sum_{k=n}^{2n} (\frac{1}{2})^k \cdot {k-1 \choose n-1}$

*here I win the k-th game and n-1 games before that, for k between n and 2n*

Im requird to rewrite this so that there is no sigma-summation. If there is anyone who would know how to do so, any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If you play $2n+1$ games you can win $n$ and your opponent can win $n+1$.  Who wins the series in that case?  Maybe you are only playing $2n$ games?

Comment: @RossMillikan First person to reach their target wins.

Comment: @RossMillikan yea I guess that would be true, this is the way the question was posed. But still, this doesn't really change the winning chance right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have played $2n$ games (pretending to keep playing if somebody wins the series before this) exactly one of you will have won enough games to win the series.  The chances you win at least $n+1$ match the chances your opponent wins $n+1$.  In addition, you win the even splits.  That should suggest how to eliminate the summation.

Comment: Doesnt this give the problem that these two outcomes are counted as two, when they should be counted as one for n = 2:

y,y,n,n,n;
y,y,n,y,n

Comment: In the original version you will never play game $2n+1$, so that doesn't matter.  You need to argue that playing the phantom games can never change the winner of the series.

Comment: Sure , but then  y,y,n,n; y,y,n,y would be counted as two when it should be counted as one outcome

Comment: Presumably in your comments you mean $y$ to be a game you win.  It is easier if you count them as two.  If you stop playing after the first two games and only count it as one outcome, that outcome has a higher probability of happening than one that takes all four games to decide the series.  If you extend all series to four games each set of four games has the same chance to happen.

Comment: Ohhh ofcourse, those cancel eachother out. The sum would then be $\sum_{k=n}^{2n} (\frac{1}{2})^{2n} {2n \choose k}$ right?

Comment: right @RossMillikan?

Comment: But you still have a sum, which you said you didn't want.  My point was that the chance you win at least $n+1$ out of $2n$ is the same as the chance your opponent wins $n+1$ out of $2n$.  Call that chance $p$.  What is left is the chance you each win $n$ out of $2n$.  Call it $q$.  That is a single term, not a sum, and we have $2p+q=1$, which lets you find $p$ without a sum.